# OpenCart content not loading in page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

I'm beginner in OpenCart and I'm trying to upload the file in server using PHP. I have done the following code. My problem is, files are sucessfully uploading in server but if there is some error I'm trying to loading the `LoadA()` function, but the result is not showing in site instead it is showing in `console.log` I don't know what is the error.

> controller/boxupload/upload.php

```
public function add()
{

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {
        if(success) //files are succesfully uploading
        {
            //doing stuff
        }
        if (it is fail)
        {

            $this->LoadA(); // this is not loading in site. Instead it is showing in console.log
        }
    }
}

public function LoadA()
{
    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
    $this->document->setTitle("!!!!!!!!!!!!Upload failed!!!!!!!!");
    $data['add'] =  $this->url->link('boxupload/upload/add', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('boxupload/upload.tpl', $data));
}
```

Then the tpl file for this one

> controller/boxupload/upload.tpl

```
$('#button-upload').on('click', function() {
    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
    $('#form-upload').remove();

    $('body').prepend('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload" style="display: none;"><input type="file" name="file" /></form>');

    $('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').trigger('click');

    if (typeof timer != 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    var WID = 30;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').val() != '') {
            clearInterval(timer);

            // Reset everything
            $('.alert').remove();
            $('#progress-bar').css('width', '0%');
            $('#progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-danger progress-bar-success');
            $('#progress-text').html('');

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo "index.php?route=boxupload/upload/add&token=$token"; ?>',

                type: 'post',
                //dataType: 'json',
                data: new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#button-upload').button('loading');

                    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '50%');

                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#button-upload').button('reset');
                    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '100%');

                },
                success: function() 
                {   $('#progress-bar').css('width', '80%');


                },

            });
        }

    }, 500);
});
```

[image: Please see the bellow image]
Please see the highlighted area in image.

Comment: you need to call $this->LoadA(); instead of $this->load(); ?

Comment: also if i am not wrong you need to set html on success or error like this: 
success: function(html) {
  $('#div-name').html(html);
},
as you have html in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataType: 'html',

success: function(html) 
{   
    $('#progress-bar').css('width', '80%');
    $('#your-div').html(html);

},
```

Comment: This is working. And please explain why the function in same controller is not working.

Comment: Because you were returning view in response but were not setting it anywhere on UI.. I don't understand what you mean by function in same controller is not working..

Answer (score 1):

Your .tpl file should be in a view.

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('boxupload/upload.tpl', $data));
```

loads the file

```
view/theme/default/template/boxupload/upload.tpl
```

Also, look at some other template files.  They're generally mostly HTML.

Also, you're going to want to refactor your names so they use normal OpenCart naming conventions.

```
controller/extension/boxupload/upload.php
view/theme/default/template/extension/boxupload/upload.tpl
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks your response. But it is not working. Throwing error like `tpl file is not found on server`.  I have fixed it by redirecting.